# Parsing a Circular Buffer

Tags: c, embedded, circular-buffer

I'm implementing a small Zigbee library for Atmel's XMEGA devices. The Zigbee radio communicates with the MCU using the internal USART.

When I started writing the library I was using the simple approach of a fixed array along with interrupts for received data. Once I had the complete command (I know I have a complete command because the Zigbee states the frame length - minus the starting delimiter and checksum at the end), I set a flag in the interrupt service routine and copied the array into another array in my main().

Once I had the array copied, another routine *ZBProcessFrame* takes over and parses the frame and takes appropriate action.

The potential issue with this approach is that while I'm copying the array another message could come and change this shared variable.

By reading online, it seems I can either switch off my interrupts while copying the array or I should use a circular buffer, as then I can avoid copying the array entirely. I've successfully implemented a 32 byte circular buffer but now my issue is, how do I tell where the actual data began and how many bytes have come since the starting delimiter. My ISR only has the following:

```
ISR(Receiver Interrupt)
{
     ring->add(USART_Data);
}
```

Should I check for the starting delimiter here and set a flag incase there's a valid command here? The main() can then look at the flag continuously and if raised, it implies there's a valid command present.

Is this a valid approach or should I look for an alternative?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The circular buffer is a good design.  I would leave the ISR as simple as possible, like you have it.  If your `main` is a super-loop then I would add a call to a new routine like `ZBReceiveFrame`, which reads the next available byte (up to all available bytes individually) from the ring buffer and processes it in a state-machine.  For example, the first state expects the start-of-frame delimiter and advances to the next state when it's received.  The next state receives and interprets the frame length.  The next state receives the frame body and the final state validates the frame CRC (all just examples).  The states could all be implemented within `ZBReceiveFrame` using a switch statement.  The state variable used within `ZBReceiveFrame` should be static so that the state is remembered from one call to the next.  When the final state identifies a valid frame it sets the flag to prompt `main` to call `ZBProcessFrame`.  Whether `ZBReceiveFrame` processes one or all available chars depends on how time-critical is the other stuff in the `main` super-loop.

This technique creates [loose coupling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loose_coupling), which is desirable.  The ISR is only responsible for receiving the byte into the ring buffer and has no knowledge of what a frame is.  `ZBReceiveFrame` only knows how to read from the ring buffer and delimit a frame but doesn't know how to interpret the data.  And `ZBProcessFrame` is responsible for interpreting the data within a frame but has no knowledge of the ring buffer.

Answer (score 1):

Your circular buffer needs to have read and write positions. WR points to next empty space, and RD to oldest received byte.

But this means that you need to manipulate these 2 variables at the same time: RD should never exceed WR for example. And since you cannot do this with single instruction, you need to disable interrupts when either one is read or written.

I have usually done it like this:

- Have a `putByte` function which is used from interrupt routine. Nothing else is done from ISR.
- Have a `getByte` function which is used from main program. This function will temporarily disable interrupts. Returns special value (`-1` or similar) if buffer is empty.
- On each main loop iteration, copy available bytes from circular buffer to main buffer. Check received data after circular buffer is empty, or main buffer is full. If there is not enough bytes, copy more on next main loop iteration. Otherwise, process frame.

Time in ISR should be short (only copy bytes to circular buffer), and time blocking ISR should be short (no error checking when reading circular buffer, only copy to main buffer)

Comment: You're missing a trick here: providing there is only one reader, and one writer (likely as it's an ISR), you only ever need to write to the WP in the ISR and RP in the consumer, and thus no potential race conditions can occur.  This arrangement yields a lock-less circular buffer.   If you're using an SMP system or CPU with out out order instruction execution you do need use memory barriers however.

Comment: No it's not: you say you're disabling interrupts when reading bytes from the buffer.  You shouldn't need to do this.

Comment: @marko I should have clarified, after posting the question I went and rewrote my code to use the circular array, much like kkrambo has described. This code only writes to the WP in the ISR and to the RP in the main loop. WP is not modified anywhere in the mainloop and the RP is not touched in the ISR.

Comment: @marko But how can you handle overwrite without locking? If consumer doesn't read buffer for a while, and it gets full, in ideal situation you overwrite oldest bytes on buffer. And then you need to modify both pointers on ISR, and need locking.

Comment: @user694733: With any circular buffer, failure to read data from it at least as fast as writing it results in overflow.  The ISR can calculate the remaining capacity from WR and RP, and will trash bytes when the buffer is full.    If you want to know that this has occurred, maintain a total count of read and written bytes in a similar fashion and do a bit of arithmetic.

Comment: @marko I don't see how that helps. You can use counters to detect and adjust RP before dereferencing it. But it is not atomic operation. What if new interrupt happens after calculation and before dereference? It is not safe.

Comment: You're missing the point: writes to the RP and WP are atomic (assuming that the RP and WP are natural word-size of the CPU) because there is only every one thread writing them. In the case where both the ISR and consumer execute concurrently, the worst that can happen is that in the case of writing, less space is apparently available in the buffer, and in the case of reading less is apparently available to read.  Naturally, the sequence of writing data to the buffer and updating the WP and updating the RP and reading is important, and must execute in that order w.r.t memory.

Comment: @marko I understand what you are saying, but I am talking about circular buffer where write to a buffer can never fail, even when buffer is full. Instead oldest byte is overwritten. You need to either A) Move RP with WP in ISR, or B) adjust RP in consumer before doing the read. Both require more than single instruction to work.

Comment: With a fixed buffer size, failing to consume items fast enough will result in skipped items anyway. In that case it's much simpler to drop them at the writer side instead of having to introduce additional synchronizing mechanisms.